# Grep a pattern from a file and get that whole word, not just the pattern

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, sort, search

1. List item

I/P:

```
abcd_Server1 CCDDomain
defg_Server1 GGFDomain
kdkhs_Server1 CCDDomain
abce_Server1 CCDDomain
dgdg_Server1 CCADomain
dfdkhs_Server1 GGFDomain
```

I need to search for the word "Domain" and then count the unique occurrences of the word.

In above case the output should be 3 since 3 different names are there (`CCDDomain`,`GGFDomain`,`CCADomain`)

I have tried using this :

```
grep -oh '*Domain' "ServerNames.txt" | sort -u | wc -l
```

('-oh' I got from another answer)

Answer (score 3):

For the number of occurrences of each of the different *words* that contain Domain, with GNU `grep` or compatible.

- for words delimited by *spacing* characters:

  ```
  <file grep -o '\S*Domain\S*' | sort | uniq -c
  ```
- for *words* defined as sequences of alnums or underscores (anything else being delimiters:

  ```
  <file grep -o '\w*Domain\w*' | sort | uniq -c
  ```

Comment: don't you need `-E` flag to enable extended regex to use `\w` ?

Comment: @Kiwy -E only affects [‘?’, ‘+’, ‘{’, ‘|’, ‘(’, and ‘)’ meta-characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap you match pattern with the `\w` pattern, like this :

```
% grep -oh "\w*Domain\w*" ServerNames.txt
CCDDomain
GGFDomain
CCDDomain
CCDDomain
CCADomain
GGFDomain
```

Then you can go ahead with `sort -u` and `wc -l`

```
% grep -oh '\w*Domain\w*' ServerNames.txt | sort -u | wc -l 
3
```

Comment: You mean `\w*`, of course?

Comment: or `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\w` if you don't want numbers and underscores to match

Answer (score 0):

Old-good **`awk`** approach:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /Domain/ && !a[$2]++{ cnt++ }END{ print cnt }' ServerNames.txt
3
```

---

With GNU `coreutils` you may apply (in case if `Domain` is always occurs as a 2nd column of each line):

```
$ uniq -f1 <(sort -k2 ServerNames.txt) | wc -l
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:]]*Domain[[:alpha:]]*' ServerNames.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

or

```
grep -o '\w*Domain\w*' ServerNames.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

`[[:alpha:]]*` means 0 or more letters. So the `grep` will find sequences of letters including 'Domain', and output them to be sorted and uniqued. (`-h` not needed when only one file is to be grepped.)